# What is Compositing mean when baking lightmap in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am baking a scene in Unity3D. I found that all things computed really quickly, but a operation called "Compositing" is very time-cosuming. What does Unity do in this operation?
[image]

Comment: Compositing is the combining of visual elements from separate sources into single images, often to create the illusion that all those elements are parts of the same scene.

Comment: [Lightning, Rendering & Compositing](https://medium.com/@sdixon3/lighting-rendering-and-compositing-2cbb8e6b990c)

Comment: I accidently find that texture compression format can influence compositing format. Setting the format to ASTC4x4 can give me 4 mins advantage than raw RGBA32. Why?